# Usage of ||, OR in PHP

Tags: php, logical-operators

I have the following code which redirect pages depends on $path.

```
...
$path = $this->uri->segment(3);
$pathid = $this->uri->segment(4);
if($path=='forsiden'){
            redirect('','refresh');
        }elseif($path =='contact'){
            redirect('welcome/kontakt','refresh');
        }elseif($path =='illustration'){
            $this->_gallery($path,$pathid);
        }elseif($path =='webdesign'){
            redirect('welcome/webdesign','refresh');    
        }elseif($path==('web_tjenester' || 'webdesigndetails' || 
                        'vismahjemmeside' || 'joomla' || 'vismanettbutikk' || 
                        'vpasp' || 'artportfolio')){
        ...
     CODE A   
     ...    

}else{
        ...
        CODE B
        ...
                }
```

I am not getting right results with

```
$path==('web_tjenester' || 'webdesigndetails' || 
'vismahjemmeside' || 'joomla' || 'vismanettbutikk' || 
'vpasp' || 'artportfolio')
```

contact, illustration, gallery and webdesign are redirected and working alright.
However all other pages are added CODE A.

I am expecting CODE A only when $path is web_tjenester', 'webdesigndetails',    'vismahjemmeside', 'joomla', 'vismanettbutikk', 'vpasp' or 'artportfolio'.

Could anyone point out my mistake and correct me please?

Thanks in advance.

--UPDATE--

The following works, but is there any ways shorten the code?

I am repeating ($path==..).

```
elseif(($path=='web_tjenester') || ($path=='webdesigndetails') || 
    ($path=='vismahjemmeside') || ($path=='joomla') || ($path=='vismanettbutikk') || 
    ($path=='vpasp') || ($path=='artportfolio')){
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`||` operator is a logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). The semantics of the expression `a || b` is that it evaluates to *true* if either `a` or `b` evaluates to *true*, and *false* otherwise.

So it cannot be used in that way you intended it as the expression `('web_tjenester' || … || 'artportfolio')` will be evaluated to a boolean value (to be specific: *true* as `'web_tjenester'` evaluates to *true* using [boolean conversion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) that then will be compared to the value of `$path`.

If you want to test if a value is in a set of values, you can use an array and test the value with [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array):

```
in_array($path, array('web_tjenester', 'webdesigndetails', 'vismahjemmeside', 'joomla', 'vismanettbutikk', 'vpasp', 'artportfolio'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$path==('web_tjenester' || 'webdesigndetails' || 
'vismahjemmeside' || 'joomla' || 'vismanettbutikk' || 
'vpasp' || 'artportfolio')
```

This is not valid syntax, you would need to have the `$path ==` in front of each string separated by ORs. The easier way to do it which looks nicer is to put all your string in an array and then use the `in_array()` function to check.

```
$array = array('web_tjenester', 'webdesigndetails', 
'vismahjemmeside', 'joomla', 'vismanettbutikk',
'vpasp', 'artportfolio');
if (in_array($path, $array)) {
    // do whatever
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is valid syntax.  However, it's obtuse and excessively complicated for what it actually does (aka useless) semantically.

Answer (score 1):

because `$path == ('x' || 'y')` means "evaluate 'x || y', and see if that equals $path. You'd need to do

```
if($path == 'x' || $path == 'y')
```

However you may want to consider a switch statement:

```
switch($patch) {
   case 'web_tjenester':
   case 'webdesigndetals':
          so_and_so();
          break; 
   case 'contact':
          redirect();
          break;
}
```

read up on switch before doing so , however :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it the way you do it: You should compare everything with $path, so

```
$path=='web_tjenester' || $path=='webdesigndetails' || 
$path=='vismahjemmeside' || $path=='joomla' || $path=='vismanettbutikk' || 
$path=='vpasp' || $path=='artportfolio'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this

```
$path==('web_tjenester' || 'webdesigndetails' || 'vismahjemmeside' || 'joomla' || 'vismanettbutikk' ||'vpasp' || 'artportfolio')
```

It should be

```
$path=='web_tjenester' || $path=='webdesigndetails' || $path=='vismahjemmeside' || $path=='joomla' ...
```

You could set the paths you are using in an array and use `[in_array()][1]` for a cleaner code.